# iOS ,I can't finish the background color translucent with UIViewcontroller and UIWindow?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, background-color, uiwindow

[Why the background color of UIWindow is black which is not my destination,and I want to make the background translucent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRRTA.png)

Comment: Check if you have set View's background color as clearColor. In that case default color will be black

Comment: what actually you want to achieve ?

Comment: @felix Please accept the answer if it solves the issue

Answer (score 0):

How can your deepest window be transparent.. What would you see? The home screen?

If you set your background to clearColor, it will just appear black. Try setting it to white and then make your view's have some sort of alpha below 1.0 to make it translucent. If I'm understanding your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

If I am guessing right you want to display the previous view in background instead of black color. If this is the case you need to set these 2 properties on the view controller you are displaying :-

```
yourpresentingVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
yourpresentingVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
[self presentViewController:tutorial animated:YES completion:NULL];
```